# why does javascript setTimeout() not work in a loop?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function timedText()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('txt');
  var t = new Array();
  t[1] = setTimeout( function(){x.value="2 seconds"}, 2000 );
  t[2] = setTimeout( function(){x.value="4 seconds"}, 4000 );
  t[3] = setTimeout( function(){x.value="6 seconds"}, 6000 );
}
function timedTextArr()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('txt');
  var t = new Array();
  for( var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
    t[i] = setTimeout( function(){x.value=i*2+" seconds"}, i*2000 );
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Display timed text!" onclick="timedText()" />
<input type="button" value="Display timed text Arr!" onclick="timedTextArr()" />
</form>
<p>Click on the button above. The input field will tell you when two, four, and six seconds have passed.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Function `timedText()` works, but `timedTextArr()` doesn't.  Both functions assign return values from `setTimeout()` to array elements.  But in the `for()` loop, only the last timer works... and it works three times.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, have a look at what closures are in Javascript.

Basically in your for loop the function

```
function(){x.value=i*2+" seconds"}
```

only "sees" one instance of the i variable.

So once the loop is over, i is equal to 3, so it is 3 for all functions.

You need to wrap the call in another anonymous function to create a scope, like this:

```
t[i] = setTimeout( (function(i){ return function(){x.value=i*2+" seconds"}})(i), i*2000 );
```

The outer function will create a new scope, and inside it i will be equal to the value of i in the loop and stay like this. You can try it out there: http://jsfiddle.net/6b68E/

Comment: Interesting.  I'll research "javascript closures".  Thx.

Answer (score 7):

The `i` in your function refers to the `i` from the loop, which is `6` by the time any of the timeouts fire. You need to add a closure/scope:

```js
for (var i = 0 ;i < 3 ;i++ ) {
  // create a closure (new scope)
  (function() {

    // make a local copy of `i` from the outer scope
    var _i = i;

    // use `i` for values that should refer to the *latest* value.
    // use the copy (`_i`) for those that need the point-in-time value.
    t[i] = setTimeout(function() { x.value = _i * 2 + " seconds" }, i*2000);
  })();
}
```

**UPDATE 2023**

Since the introduction of `let`, you can now scope your counter variable to the loop.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => x.value = `${i * 2} seconds`, i * 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting the same results is `setTimeout` is asynchronous.  Which means it doesn't run until the rest of the script is finished.  Then once it runs the value of `i` is set to equal 3 so all the functions run and all they see is that i = 3.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that due to the asynchronous nature of timer functions, the loop is done running before the first timeout is called, and therefore `i` is set to 2 by the time the *first* timeout runs, and stays the same for the other two timeouts

To overcome this, you should consider refactoring the code to use an *interval* instead, which allows you to change the value of `i` in sync with the closures:

```
var i=1;

var handle = setInterval( function() {

x.value = (i*2) + "seconds";
i++;
if (i>3) clearInterval(handle);

}, 2000 );
```

Other than that the loop is running from 0 to 2, instead of 1 to 3, like in `timedText()`

Comment: That's okay, as I wanted the first setTimeout() to be 0 seconds so that the user sees something immediately.