# In React event handler, How to make multiple setState calls safely?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
    function App() {

      // array to store 3 numbers, all initialized to 0
      const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState<number[]>([0, 0, 0]);

      // increments counter[i] by 1
      const increment = (i: number) => {
        let newCount = [...counter];
        newCount[i] += 1;  
        setCounter(newCount);
      }

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <p>            
              count: {counter[0]} {counter[1]} {counter[2]}
            </p>
            <button onClick={() => {
              [0, 1, 2].map((i) => {  
                // pretend that setTimeout is making some web request
                setTimeout(() => increment(i), 1000); 
              });
            }} >Increment All</button>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

When I click on the button, I want it to increment all 3 numbers in the array, but it looks like only the last `setTimeout` call will take effect (and thus only one of the values get incremented).

I think I understand why that is (the `counter` value is constant within the react `onClick` event handler call), but I don't know how best to structure this code to avoid this issue. Do I have to buffer the increments and "commit" the changes all at once via one call to `setCounter`? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `console.log` in your `increment` function shows the error:

```
  const increment = (i: number) => {
    let newCount = [...counter];
    // log values here
    console.log(i, counter)
    newCount[i] += 1;  
    setCounter(newCount);
  }
```

The log reads:

```
"0, [0, 0, 0]"
"1, [0, 0, 0]"
"2, [0, 0, 0]"
```

The value of `counter` is always `[0, 0, 0]`. This is caused by **closures**.

When you call `setTimeout(() => increment(i), 1000)` for each of the values in `[0, 1, 2]`, JavaScript creates three functions in memory:

```
() => increment(0)

() => increment(1)

() => increment(2)
```

These functions will execute after 1 second.

However, as these need to use the `increment` function, the `increment` function is also 'copied' into memory.

The `increment` function also uses the `counter` variable, so the `counter` variable is *also* copied into memory - with its current value `[0, 0, 0]`.

This is the value that will be used in all three functions.

This is why you are seeing only the last value increment, because you're essentially doing this:

```
 setCounter([1, 0, 0])
 setCounter([0, 1, 0])
 setCounter([0, 0, 1])
```

---

One solution would be to not use `setTimeout` at all, **but a more robust solution is to provide a callback function to `setCounter`**:

```
const increment = (i: number) => {
  setCounter(prev => {
    let newCount = [...prev]
    newCount[i] += 1
    return newCount
  })
}
```

The rule is, if the new state values depends on the old state value (e.g., when incrementing a number, the new value is determined by the old value) then you should pass a callback to set state.

You cannot rely on `counter` being an up to date value.

---

Please see [D. Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61448458/7578157) for some useful links relating to closures and `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [JMadeleine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61448395/6162550), you can get around that issue by putting some scope around the setTimeout call in the form of a function.

```
[0,1,2].map((i) => {
  (function() {
    setTimeout(() => increment(i),1000);
  })() // <- call that new function
});
```

---

See these posts for some helpful info

[why does javascript setTimeout() not work in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384719/why-does-javascript-settimeout-not-work-in-a-loop)

https://coderwall.com/p/_ppzrw/be-careful-with-settimeout-in-loops